# PHP Javascript maintenance page

Tags: javascript, php, maintenance-mode

I used this in my index.php

```
<?
    include('config.php');
    if($site->maintenance > 0){
        echo "<script>document.location.href='maintenance'</script>";
        exit;
    }
?>
```

and in my config.php after checked database connection

```
$site = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM problems"));
```

I made a table in my database and called it `problems` but even when I put the value 0, it transfers me to maintenance. When I checked the variable `$site` by `var_dump($site)` it outputs:

```
bool(false)
```

and if I checked it like this: `var_dump($site->maintenance)` it outputs:

```
NULL
```

What do I have to do to manage the maintenance from database and when I want my site to work I change value?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM problems` LOL! :D Looks like *this* query succeeded. :) (Don't take it personal)

Comment: LOOOOOL :D finally solved the problem and changed the name :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are using JS for this? What if user JS is off? I would use PHP instead

Create a table for maintenance with a column say `maintenance_status`, now this will hold a boolean value, 0 1... 0 => off, 1 => on, will keep only a single record which will be created once, and later will update it always...

So now later you create this function

```
function check_maintenance($connection) { /* Call this function on every page, 
                                          pass your database connection var 
                                          as a function parameter */
   $query = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM tbl_maintenance LIMIT 1")); 
   /* Limit 1 is optional if you are using only 1 row as I told you, 
      if you are keeping records of the previous maintenance, probably 
      you've to sort desc and use limit 1 */

   if($query['tbl_maintenance'] == '1') { //Check boolean value, if it's on than redirect
      header('Location: maintenance.php'); //Redirect the user to maintenance page
      exit;
   }
}
```

Comment: this not working ... i login to phpmyadmin and i set tinyint value 0 ... it appears tinyint(4) i do not know this normal or what 

and if i set it to 1 .... tinyint(1) ... no maintenance page

Comment: @user1477332 It indicates the length of that integer val to be accepted

Comment: then i am doing well in phpmyadmin .. but code not working yet

Comment: @user1477332 only 1 is also valid

Comment: not the same to me ... just 1 ... appear maintenance.php whatever the value in phpmyadmin 0 or 1

Comment: @user1477332 PHP is not a strict language, if you use === than it will fail but using == '1' or == 1 is same thing, PHP will smartly convert that string to integer

Comment: now it's working with me .. thanks for help man (error was from the row) i just made new rows instead of edit the first row ... thanks again man .... but one last question--->  What if user JS is off ?? what kind of error will appear to user ??????

Comment: @user1477332 If you are using my code only than nothing will happen even if the user turns off JS :) and you welcome

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `$site` is `false`, could being caused by problem with the query. Change the mysql code to:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM problems");
if(!$result) {
    die(mysql_error();
}

$site = mysql_fetch_object($result);
```

Further you should learn howto enable error messages in PHP. I guess there are bunch of them. They are disabled by default as it could be a security risk in a production system. But when you are developing you **MUST** enable them. You can enable it in the `php.ini` of development system:

*php.ini*:

```
...
display_errors=1
...
log_errors=1
...
error_log="/path/to/writable/file"
...
error_reporting=E_ALL
```

After modifying the `php.ini` don't forget to restart the web server.